# Irreducibility over $ \mathbb{Q} ( \sqrt{2} , \sqrt{3})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Show that $x^5-9 x^3 +15x +6$ is irreducible over $ \mathbb{Q} ( \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$

Comment: *Combine Eisenstein and the fact that four and five are coprime.* It is difficult to help you unless you tell us what tools and bits of theory have been covered up to this point. If my hints (essentially isomorphic to those by k.stm) are all Greek to you, then you will need to review quite a bit. But you have to help us help yourself.

Answer (score 3):

*Some directions*:

- Show that $x^5 - 9x^3 + 15x + 6$ is irreducible over $ℚ$. Let $α$ be root of it.
- What can you say about $ℚ(α)$ and $ℚ(√2, √3,α)$?
- What can you say about the minimal polynomial of $α$ over $ℚ(√2,√3)$?